# Adding AND statement to ColdFusion query

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to add **AND ActiveFlag = 'Y'** (value in same table as CommitteeRoleCode), but all my attempts either brake it or are ignored. Would anyone be kind enough to assist?

*Thanks for your time!*

```
<cfparam name="attributes.Address" default="">
<cfparam name="attributes.CommitteeID" default="0">
<cfparam name="attributes.AddressListName" default="">

<cfif Len(Trim(attributes.CommitteeID)) EQ 0>
    <cfset attributes.CommitteeID = 0>
</cfif>

<cfif Len(Trim(attributes.Address))>
    <cfset result = "">
    <cfloop list="#attributes.Address#" index="i">
        <cfif Refind("\[{1}.+\]{1}", i)>
            <!---looking for the 'ALL' member type to grab all categories--->
            <cfif i EQ "[ALL]">
                <cfset l_where = "a.CommitteeRoleCode IS NOT NULL AND c.EmailAddress IS NOT NULL">
            <cfelse>
                <cfset l_where = "a.CommitteeRoleCode=#Chr(39)##ReReplace(i, "\[|\]", "", "ALL")##Chr(39)# AND c.EmailAddress IS NOT NULL">
            </cfif>

            <cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#" name="MemberTypeEmails">
                Select c.EmailAddress
                from (Committee_Role_Ref as a Inner Join Committee_Member as b on a.CommitteeRoleCode=b.CommitteeRoleCode)
                    Inner Join Contact as c on b.ContactID=c.ContactID
                Where #ReReplace(l_where, "\'\'", "'", "ALL")#
                    AND b.CommitteeID=#attributes.CommitteeID#
            </cfquery>
            <cfloop query="MemberTypeEmails">
                <cfif ReFind("[^#chr(13)##chr(10)##chr(9)##chr(32)#]@{1}.+\..+", EmailAddress)>
                    <cfif Len(Trim(result))>
                        <cfset result = result & "," & EmailAddress>
                    <cfelse>
                        <cfset result = EmailAddress>
                    </cfif>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        <cfelseif ReFind(".+@{1}.+\..+", i)>
            <cfif Len(Trim(result))>
                <cfset result = result & "," & i>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset result = i>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfset "caller.#attributes.AddressListName#" = result>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Is `activeFlag` a varchar-type or a boolean-type in your database? And is this coming from a framework (asking because of use of `attributes`)? And what is the datatype of `attributes.CommitteeID`? It looks like it could potentially come through as a varchar-type and break your query. And finally, what is your database type?

Comment: Also, there are a couple of SQL Injection opportunities in `CommitteeID` and `CommitteeRoleCode` when it goes into `i`. Look at using `<cfqueryparam>`.

Comment: To your issue, where are you trying to add `AND ActiveFlag = 'Y'` and what error is it giving you?

Comment: I'm guessing this code is included in a page being called in a `<cfmodule>`? Can you provide some examples of the inputs you'd be supplying to this page?

Comment: To further explain @Shawn's SQL injection warning.  The <cfif> statement should be inside the <cfquery> tags.  You don't need to use ReReplace().  Just move that logic inside of <cfquery> and use <cfqueryparam> tags to protect the query from injection attacks.

Comment: @ScottJibben I believe he's using that `REReplace()` to replace escaped single-quotes (\') or to remove escaped brackets (\ [ or \ ]) from his input data.  IMO, there's a lot of input data clean up going on in that module that would probably be better handled in its own function.

Comment: @shawn, yes, that is what it looks like.  Probably simulating what the DE() function does.  cfqueryparam should make that an unnecessary step.

Comment: Since it's a dynamic query it would *greatly* help others to assist you if you posted A) the SQL string that's generated from the original query and B) the CREATE TABLE statement for the 3 tables involved and C) Post a sample of the query results, indicating how they differ from the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to add AND ActiveFlag = 'Y' (value in same table as CommitteeRoleCode). However, the value CommitteeRoleCode appears in two tables and I know this because of this part of the query

a.CommitteeRoleCode = b.CommitteeRoleCode

My suggestion would be to find out which table the ActiveFlag is really in and then prefix it accordingly in the query with either the a. or b.  ie

```
AND a.ActiveFlag = 'Y'
```

or

```
AND b.ActiveFlag = 'Y'
```

Then place your AND clause where indicated below. But if you want more help you should also post what error message you are receiving.

```
            <cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#" name="MemberTypeEmails">
                Select c.EmailAddress
                from (Committee_Role_Ref as a Inner Join Committee_Member as b on a.CommitteeRoleCode=b.CommitteeRoleCode)
                    Inner Join Contact as c on b.ContactID=c.ContactID
                Where #ReReplace(l_where, "\'\'", "'", "ALL")#
                    AND b.CommitteeID=#attributes.CommitteeID#
                    -- AND a. or b. ActiveFlag goes here 
                    AND a.ActiveFlag = 'Y'
            </cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! That's what I was thinking, but when I run it as **b.** it's ignored and it sends an email to both ActiveFlag Y and N emails of the specified CommitteeRoleCode . When I run it as **a.** no email is fired and the error log says "Ballot Error: CommitteeID: 132&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VoterContactID: 221968 " The weird thing is VoterContactID: 221968 belongs to an email that is ActiveFlag Y but ISN'T a recipient of the email because its CommitteeRoleCode is not set to receive it.

Comment: These automated emails based off triggers is a rat's nest of code. Do you see any reason why I can't require ActiveFlag=Y here, and instead need to do it somewhere else up or down the chain?

Comment: Ugg. There must be something else mucking it up. I found a place to kick off the email in the UI (used to test formatting) and adding the AND `b.ActiveFlag='Y` works for that, but event triggered emails are still going to N emails. This code must be touching it (cuz I can break the event :| ) but must need to catch it elsewhere. Thanks anyway, @WilGeno !

Comment: Can you supply more info about your actual database structure? It looks like `ActiveFlag` may be in your `Committee_Member` table, but you should verify. Also, if the options are only 'Y' and 'N', you should probably try to make this a real boolean type instead of a string. What type of database are you using?

Comment: Where is `Ballot Error:...` coming from? Is this a `try/catch` around the `cfmodule` call?

Comment: What is stored in the value l_where ? This is going to make a huge difference to the query when this is added to the where clause #ReReplace(l_where, "\'\'", "'", "ALL")#  .